# Xamarin: Dos controles picker, uno dependiente de otro

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xaml

Edito, gracias por la ayuda @Brian593.

Tengo el primer desplegable y me detecta cuando selecciono otro de la lista, ahora necesito que el segundo desplegable cambie sus items dependiendo del primero, dejo el código a continuación:

```
public class DatosBaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    ...

    #region Properties

    public ObservableCollection<UnidadObra> UnidadesObra { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<UnidadObraGrupo> UnidadesObraGrupo { get; set; }
    public UnidadObraGrupo SelectedUnidadObraGrupo { get; set; }
    int unidadObraGrupoSelectedIndex;
    public int UnidadObraGrupoSelectedIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return unidadObraGrupoSelectedIndex;
        }
        set
        {
            if (unidadObraGrupoSelectedIndex != value)
            {
                unidadObraGrupoSelectedIndex = value;

                // trigger some action to take such as updating other labels or fields
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(UnidadObraGrupoSelectedIndex));
                SelectedUnidadObraGrupo = UnidadesObraGrupo[UnidadObraGrupoSelectedIndex];
            }
            UnidadesObra = new ObservableCollection<UnidadObra>(UnidadesObraTotal.Where(l => l.Grupo == SelectedUnidadObraGrupo.Cod));
        }
    }

    // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
    #endregion

    ...
```

Para ser más concreto, la idea es que el desplegable **UnidadObra** cambie en función de lo que se haya seleccionado en **UnidadObraGrupo**.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Usa el patron MVVM y el control bindable picker, al cambiar el primero notificas a la aplicacion el cambio un ejemplo lo tienes aquí https://blog.xamarin.com/new-bindable-picker-control-xamarin-forms/
[image]
<sub>(fuente: [xamarin.com](https://blog.xamarin.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/BindablePicker_Android.gif))</sub>

Comment: Hola @Brian593 , he editado la pregunta con un ejemplo concreto, a ver si sabe ayudarme, de nuevo gracias por su ayuda.